# Anyone else having or heard about audio/midi issues since latest kernel update (Ubuntu Studio/Kubuntu 20.0.4)?

Tags: kernel, ram, audio-recording, midi

In the last couple of days I have been having audio/midi issues, on two separate laptops, both running the same distro (Ubuntu Studio over Kubuntu). It's been happening while working on the same project I've been working on for months - same DAW, same plugins, synths, etc. The only thing that has changed as far as I can tell is that both laptops recently got a kernel update, and I'm pretty sure *only* the kernel was updated.

The main issue is very frequent x-runs, especially when the automation in one of my QTractor tracks triggers tunnel reverb in Yoshimi - and again, I've been using this track through this DAW with this effect for months with basically no x-runs at all. I also had some audio dropouts on the other laptop while simply recording a single audio track in Audacity. On the main laptop, the issue becomes less severe with each thing I unplug from Jack (i.e. Carla, a second audio card - all of which I have been using all along with no issues), so it *does* seem memory-related. However, my system has lots of memory.

The system monitor shows I'm only using 1.5 of my 19.3 GB RAM, zero swap, CPU load 4%. I have noticed in the system monitor that "baloo_file" seems to be using a decent amount of memory, although not nearly as much as my audio software. (I only mention it because it says systemd is its parent and I would think systemd might have been part of the kernel update... and because I've seen mention in recent months of people having problems with some systemd-related memory-handling process.)

I'm using everything through Jack (but with ALSA as the driver), QjackCtl version 0.5.0 (not sure if Jack under the hood uses the same version number).

For the laptop I'm having the most issues with, my info is:

- Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
- Qt Version: 5.12.8
- Kernel Version: 5.4.0-124-lowlatency
- OS Type: 64-bit
- Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz
- Memory: 19.3 GiB of RAM

The other laptop is an older i5 Asus, also Intel, using the same software versions.

Anyone else been having this issue or know anything about a fix?

Comment: Dang, I didn't even think to try the previous kernel... which I have done for other issues. I only started thinking the issue was kernel-related today, after initially thinking the problem lay elsewhere.Thanks, I will try that. In the meantime, stupid question: how do I file a bug report. I've only tried that with Kubuntu, specifically, but abandoned the effort when I realized that my email address becomes available for every logged-in user to see.

Comment: Task 1 is to isolate the problem so that it is reproducible with the minimum amount of software in a minimum number of steps. The more unnecessary variables you can eliminate to demonstrate the problem reliably, the better.

Comment: Task 2 is to determine which software package has the bug. Sometimes this is easy, sometimes this is hard. For example, if you can demonstrate that the problem is really a kernel bug, then then package is 'linux'. The you simply run `ubuntu-bug <package_name>` and follow the prompts.

Comment: Perfect. I have already trouble-shot the software I'm using, but I will try the earlier kernel and see what happens. Thanks again.

Comment: Task 3 is to answer the follow-up question from the Triager and eventually from the Developer. They *always* have questions, so a valid email address (Launchpad account) is important. If they don't hear back from you, they just mark the bug INVALID and move on to the next bug.

Comment: Scan the bug reports on launchpad.net before you file. If somebody *already* reported the bug, mark that it affects you too, and subscribe to the bug so you can follow the progress.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is adequate as an "answer" to my post, but I took an action and the issue seems to be solved, so I'll post it here.

I booted into the previous kernel and my problem went away. Then I rebooted into the current kernel where I was having the trouble and things seem to be working properly again. I don't know if booting into the earlier kernel somehow reset something which persisted when I booted into the current one or what, but the problem seems to be gone. Fingers crossed that it stays that way.